# SceneKit App fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS9

Tags: objective-c, crash, ios9, scenekit

We've bumped into a problem with one of our apps that uses SceneKit when deployed on iOS9.  The app works great on iOS8.0-8.4, but when deployed on iOS9, it immediately crashes.  Looking at the crash logs, we are seeing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in a thread. The specific error states com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.SCNView Thread 11 crashed.  Thinking that it was somehow related to the complexity of the scene, we dropped the scene back to nothing but a 3d box, and the app still crashes.  The code that renders the box is as follows.  It seems awfully simple to be crashing.  And it's very weird that this runs fine on everything prior to iOS9 and runs fine on the simulator for iOS9.  It only crashes when deployed. (This is an Enterprise app).

The crash occurs on the line of code that reads:
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];

What am I missing??  Thanks for any help.

```
@implementation TreasureChestViewController
@synthesize sceneView; 

 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
 {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
     if (self) {
     // Custom initialization

     }
     return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Create the SCNView

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Add scene an empty scene
    scene = [SCNScene scene];

    // Set the scene to the view
    sceneView.scene = scene;

    // Create and add a camera to the scene
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0,15, 30);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

    // Create and add a light to the scene
    SCNLight *spotLight = [SCNLight light];
    spotLight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot;
    spotLight.color = [UIColor whiteColor];
    SCNNode *spotLightNode = [SCNNode node];
    spotLightNode.light = spotLight;
    spotLightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, cameraNode.position.y, 20);

    [cameraNode addChildNode:spotLightNode];

    // A square box
    CGFloat boxSide = 15.0;
    SCNBox *box = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:boxSide
                                height:boxSide
                                length:boxSide
                         chamferRadius:0];
    SCNNode *boxNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:box];
    // boxNode.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2/3, 0, 1, 0);

    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:boxNode];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine to me. It's bizarre that it crashes only on the device, and only for iOS9. Seeing as iOS9 added Metal to SceneKit, and (capable) devices now default to using Metal for graphics, whereas the simulator still uses GL, I'd suggest it may be an issue with Metal?

Comment: are you using any custom GLSL shaders or custom GL code somewhere?

Comment: We are not using any Custom GLSL shaders.  The code above is the full source of what fails.  I'm going to produce a version that disables Metal in favor of GL and see if it runs.  These are great tips.  Thanks!  I will post back with what we find.

Comment: @FatherTimeBK What did you find?  Did GL fix it?  I'm seeing something similar, but only on a GL device.

Comment: Unfortunately, we were never able to get around this problem.  Due to time constraints, we had to change the UI to not use SceneKit at all.

Comment: Hey there - it's me, from the future in 2017, and still seeing this error when changing a node's parent twice in one frame. Very spooky and unsolved.

Comment: Not to say "Me too!" but I believe this issue is ongoing into iOS 11.